# Project9.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations

Tags: java, unsafe, operations, unchecked

```
public class Project9
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        InventoryItem[] items = new InventoryItem[3];

        items[0] = new InventoryItem("Coffee", 1);
        items[1] = new InventoryItem("Pencils", 2);
        items[2] = new InventoryItem("Notebooks", 3);

        System.out.println("Before sorting");
        System.out.println(items[0]);
        System.out.println(items[1]);
        System.out.println(items[2]);

        InventoryItem.sort(items, items.length);

        System.out.println("After sorting");
        System.out.println(items[0]);
        System.out.println(items[1]);
        System.out.println(items[2]);
    }
}

class InventoryItem implements Comparable<InventoryItem>
{
    private String name;
    private int uniqueItemID;

    public InventoryItem()
    {
        name = " ";
        uniqueItemID = 0;
    }

    public InventoryItem(String newName, int newItemID)
    {
        name = newName;
        uniqueItemID = newItemID;
    }

    public InventoryItem(InventoryItem i)
    {
        name = i.name;
        uniqueItemID = i.uniqueItemID;
    }

    public void setName(String newName)
    {
        name = newName;
    }

    public void setItemID(int newItemID)
    {
        uniqueItemID = newItemID;
    }

    public int getItemID()
    {
        return uniqueItemID;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public int compareTo(InventoryItem i)
    {
        int anotherUniqueID = ((InventoryItem) i).getItemID();
        return (this.uniqueItemID - anotherUniqueID);
    }

    public static void sort(Comparable[] a, int numberUsed)
    {
        int index, indexOfNextSmallest;

        for(index = 0; index < numberUsed - 1; index++)
        {
            indexOfNextSmallest = indexOfSmallest(index, a, numberUsed);
            interchange(index, indexOfNextSmallest, a);
        }
    }

    private static int indexOfSmallest(int startIndex, Comparable[] a, int numberUsed)
    {
        Comparable min = a[startIndex];
        int indexOfMin = startIndex;
        int index;

        for(index = startIndex + 1; index < numberUsed; index++)
        {
            if(a[index].compareTo(min) < 0)
            {
                min = a[index];
                indexOfMin = index;
            }
        }
        return indexOfMin;
    }

    private static void interchange(int i, int j, Comparable[] a)
    {
        Comparable temp;
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }
}
```

When I compile my code it throws the error message "Project9.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations."

When I recompile with Xlint:unchecked like it recommends, I get this message "warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to compareTo(T) as a member of the raw type Comparable

```
        if(a[index].compareTo(min) < 0)
                             ^
```

where T is a type-variable:

```
T extends Object declared in interface Comparable
```

What do I need to do/understand so I can fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: Please don't paste a link to code, but rather paste the *code itself*. I've taken the liberty of doing this for you, but next time, we appreciate it if you take the effort and do this yourself.

Comment: Note that what you're seeing is a warning, not an error. Your code will compile, but is at *some* risk since you're not using generics. For now, if you haven't yet learned generics, you can ignore the warning. Either that or go to the generics tutorial and study them.

Comment: How would I go about using generics? I am in an entry level OOP class and don't recognize that term.

Comment: Google the tutorial. Your a variable is a Comparable, not a `Comparable<Inventory>` type. Consider declaring it as the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add cast to InventoryItem?

```
private static int indexOfSmallest(int startIndex, Comparable<InventoryItem>[] a, int numberUsed)
{
    Comparable<InventoryItem> min = a[startIndex];
    int indexOfMin = startIndex;
    int index;

    for(index = startIndex + 1; index < numberUsed; index++)
    {
        if(a[index].compareTo((InventoryItem) min) < 0)
        {
            min = a[index];
            indexOfMin = index;
        }
    }
    return indexOfMin;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: No, generics are used specifically to *avoid* the need for such casting.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Comparable as your method parameter but rather InventoryItem.

For example:

```
private static int indexOfSmallest(int startIndex, InventoryItem[] a, int numberUsed)
{
    InventoryItem min = a[startIndex];
    int indexOfMin = startIndex;
    int index;

    for(index = startIndex + 1; index < numberUsed; index++)
    {
        if(a[index].compareTo(min) < 0)
        {
            min = a[index];
            indexOfMin = index;
        }
    }
    return indexOfMin;
}

private static void interchange(int i, int j, InventoryItem[] a)
{
    InventoryItem temp;
    temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
```

This way the compiler can do compile-time type checking to make sure that your parameter is the correct type.